# Not able to run tests in docker/gatling in different folder path than /home/gatling

Tags: scala, docker, jvm, containers, gatling

I'm trying to run tests in gatling in docker and everything works fine for the command:

**`docker run -it --rm -v /c/CURRENTPATH/conf:/opt/gatling/conf -v /c/CURRENTPATH/user_files:/opt/gatling/user-files -v /c/CURRENTPATH/results:/opt/gatling/results -e JAVA_OPTS="-Ddebug=true" <IMAGE_NAME>`**

But when I change *CURRENTPATH* to *DIFFERENT_PATH* (I copied same files from *CURRENTPATH* to *DIFFERENT_PATH*) instead of getting simulation's list in docker command line, I get:

> `08:40:51.109 [main] DEBUG io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - All initially invalidated sources: Set()`
>
> `08:40:51.117 [main] DEBUG io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation successful`
>
> `08:40:54.420 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
>   There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/
>   simulations`
>
> `08:40:54.893 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown - Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hookenter code here`

Did anyone get the same issue? Any ideas what could be wrong?